# How to set an api path during the build process of a vue application based on environment variable?

Tags: vue.js

I am wondering if there is a way to change a 'root path' for my site's api which is a string value of a variable at build time in a vue application. I would like the value of my api path to be read in during the build process and set. This functionality exists in angular, and I am wondering if it exists in vue. I have checked the docs and do not see anything similar. This [blog](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be) describes the functionality that I am after in angular. If there is nothing similar how does one change the root path of an api from for example 'localhost:8080' to 'example.mysite.com' at build time so that the right path is set when building/deploying to production and not needed to be changed manually? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can we see what you're using to bundle your code now? and your `scripts` defined in package.json? There's a few ways you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it in an environment variable during the build and access it via `process.env.MY_VARIABLE`.

During development you would use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv and have a `.env` file with your environment variables but in production you would set it in your CI or build script.

> Bare in mind if this is browser based then you will need to replace
>   `process.env` references with the explicit values which you can do with most bundlers.